# Digikam unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 digikam : Depends: libkface1 (>= 1.0~digikam2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: kipi-plugins but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: mplayerthumbs but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: If you solved this question, add an answer how you did so and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try (on the command line):

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it doesn't solve the problem, pasting the output in your question might be useful.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your quick reply. Meanwhile I also looked at Mikevaughn repositories where i found a similar hint as yours. It worked, I am the proud user now of Digikam 2.9.0. Have used Digikam for years but since I bought the Fuji X-S1 could no longer edit RAW images as Fuji began using a different array of pixels in their new sensor.
Digikam 2.9.0 does the trick. Thanks again, greetings, Miel

Comment: @miel: You can close this question by either accepting my answer (if you wish), or opting to remove the question (if you feel it was answered satisfactorily elsewhere).